# Python code for appending list / matrix to R

Tags: python, r, list, numpy, matrix

I am running a recurrent neural network model (LSTM) and want to make my matrix 3-dimensional. I have 15 variables in each "row" and each "row" corresponds to a week of data. I need to fill in the first four rows with "0"s so that I can begin from my analysis from the fifth row.

I have the following code in Python:

```py
matrix = 15variables.as_matrix()
n = len(matrix)
k = 5

x_list = []
for i in range(k-1): 
    x_list.append(np.zeros(15))
for i in range(n):
    x_list.append(matrix[i,:])
x = np.array([x_list[i:i+k] for i in range(n)])
```

The above code makes the matrix look like something like this (normally [154., 165., 83., ... ] is the first entry otherwise :

```
array([[[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [154., 265.,  83., ..., 152.,  58., 170.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [154., 265.,  83., ..., 152.,  58., 170.],
        [102., 229.,  78., ..., 182.,  74., 204.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [154., 265.,  83., ..., 152.,  58., 170.],
        [102., 229.,  78., ..., 182.,  74., 204.],
        [101., 267.,  87., ..., 175.,  82., 182.]],
```

How can I convert this to R code? I am trying

```
k = 5
for (i in 1:k){
        x [[i]]= append.zeros(15)
       }
```

in R , but I'm unfamiliar with how this works in R and I get "Error in append(15) : argument "values" is missing, with no default".

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not familiar with python but in R a matrix is always two-dimensional. 
Higher dimensional matrix-like objects are referred to as arrays.

Comment: What is `append.zeros`? Even in Python this fails. Apparently all you are doing is assigning a [1-d array of zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) which are atomic vectors in R: `x[[i]] <- rep(0, 15)`.

Comment: @Hi thanks for replying. I'm

Comment: I would create an array of zeros, something like `array(0, c(n, k, 15))` or something, and fill the data into the necessary sheets.  But I have to admit I don't quite understand what do you want to achieve--the description you provide suggests just adding 4 rows of zeros and has nothing to do with 3D objects...